# Mongo: search for values in one collection that do not exist in another

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm working on a database project and I have a collection called 'Business' which has the field 'businessId' and a total of 77,445 records.

I also have another collection called Reviews that also has the field 'businessId' but with a whooping 2,225,213 total records in the collection!

I'm new to non-relational databases and my database senses are telling me something is off with these numbers. 2225213/77445 give us a 28 reviews per business. So I want to verify that there are no 'Reviews' records that have 'businessId's that do not exist in the 'Business' collection.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To confirm your hunch, you could first count the distinct businessId's in the Reviews collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for SQL ANTI-JOIN like , in MongoDB , the only way to do it ,is by using Map Reduce ,  see below example ( long but do what you needs )

http://stuporglue.org/mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial-with-complete-code/

I hope you will dind it useful

Thanks